# Are operands inside an expression promoted to larger types according to the following rules?

Tags: c#, operators, implicit-conversion

If numeric expression contains operands (constants and variables) of different numeric types, are operands promoted to larger types according to the following rules:

1. if operands are of types `byte`, `sbyte`, `char`, `short`, `ushort`, they get converted to `int` type
2. If one of the operands is `int`, then all operands are converted to `int`
3. if expression also contains operands of types `uint` and `int`, then all operands are converted to `long`
4. If one of operands is `long`, then all operands are converted to `long`
5. if expression contains operands of type `ulong` and `long`, then operands are converted to `float`
6. If one of the operands is `float`, then all operands are converted to `float`
7. if one of operands is `double`, then all operands are converted to `double`

---

Assuming numeric expressions contains operands of different types, will all operands first get converted to a single numeric type, and only then will the runtime try to compute the result? For example, if variables `b1` and `b2` are of `byte` type, while `i1` is of `int` type, will `b1` and b2 `get` converted to int prior to computing `(b1+b2)`:

```
int i2=(b1+b2)+i1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses are of higher precedence than `+`, so the conversion would normally take place after `b1` and `b2` have been added. However, the `+` operator [does not have an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691365%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) for `byte`s, so the `byte`s must first be promoted to `int`s.

Further reading:

- [operator precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28VS.71%29.aspx)
- [binary numeric promotion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691330%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I haven't yet covered operator overloading, so my question may be way off...but what has precedence and operator overloading have to do with whether b1 and b2 will be promoted to int before or after b1+b2?

Comment: If there was an overload of the + operator that took bytes as operands, there would be no need to promote b1 and b2 to int prior to the parenthesized addition. Imagine you had `(i1 + i2) + l`, where `i1` and `i2` are `int`s and `l` is a `long`. The parenthesized addition would yield an `int`, which would then be promoted to `long` in order to add it to `l`.

Comment: So int has + operator overload that can take int as operands, and similarly, types float, double, ulong, decimal also have + operator overloaded, while sbyte, byte and short don't have operator + overloaded?

Comment: @flock: yes, see the first link (inside the first paragraph) in my answer for a list of + overloads.

Answer (score 1):

Your rules have some elements of truths, but is technically imprecise.

Here are the relevant excerpts from the C# Language Specification

> #### [7.2.6.2 Binary numeric promotions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691330%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)
>
> Binary numeric promotion occurs for the operands of the predefined `+`, `–`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `==`, `!=`, `>`, `<`, `>=`, and `<=` binary operators. Binary numeric promotion implicitly converts both operands to a common type which, in case of the non-relational operators, also becomes the result type of the operation. Binary numeric promotion consists of applying the following rules, in the order they appear here:
>
> - If either operand is of type `decimal`, the other operand is converted to type `decimal`, or a compile-time error occurs if the other operand is of type `float` or `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `double`, the other operand is converted to type `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other operand is converted to type `float`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `ulong`, the other operand is converted to type `ulong`, or a compile-time error occurs if the other operand is of type `sbyte`, `short`, `int`, or `long`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other operand is converted to type `long`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `uint` and the other operand is of type `sbyte`, `short`, or `int`, both operands are converted to type `long`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `uint`, the other operand is converted to type `uint`.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

---

> `int i2=(b1+b2)+i1`

As per the specification above, yes, `byte b1, b2` are subject to binary numeric promotion to `int` for the binary operator `+`.